# How to remove empty elements after class?(jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a series of elements after a certain class that are empty or having a white space inside it.

```
<div class="post-content">
     <div class="slider-1-smart">
     --- contents of the slider ---
     </div>

     <div></div>
     <div>   </div>

     <ul>
         <li>Text 1</li>
         <li>Text 2</li>
         <li>Text 3</li>
     </ul>  
</div>
```

This is the code that i tried so far:

```
$(function() {
    $('.post-content > div:empty').each(function() {

        j(this).remove();

    });
});
```

The result of that code is that the slider container also dissappears. What is the way to select elements after class="slider-1-smart" and remove it

Please let me know, THanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`:empty` psuedo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aempty) only selects elements that are completely empty. In other words, if it has whitespace, it's technically not considered empty.

You could select all the following sibling `div` elements with `.nextAll()` and then filter them based on whether the trimmed HTML is equal to an empty string:

[**Example Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/p3onet9L/)

```
$('.post-content > .slider-1-smart').nextAll('div').filter(function() {
  return $.trim($(this).html()) === '';
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to check the slider element contents, all you need to do is make one modification to your code. Add `.not("slider-1-smart")` to the selector chain.

```
$(function() {
    $('.post-content > div:empty').not(".slider-1-smart").each(function() {

        $(this).remove();

    });
});
```